# bson cannot be converted to DBObject

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to query a mongodb as it is shown in example on the official documentation page but it gives me the following error on Netbeans

> bson cannot be converted to DBObject

Here is the code

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);

// Now connect to your databases
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("webAppDB");
System.out.println(db.getCollectionNames());
System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("users");
Document myDoc = collection.find(eq("i", 71)).first(); // Error Line
```

The link to the example
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`DBCollection`](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html) where method find() has signature [`DBCursor find(DBObject query)`](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find-com.mongodb.DBObject-), so you should pass `DBObject` as its argument.

Whereas eq() method is defined in [Filters](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html) and has signature [`<TItem> Bson eq(String fieldName, TItem value)`](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html#eq-java.lang.String-TItem-), so it returns `Bson` type, not `DBObject`.

To pass `Bson` type to find() method you should use [`MongoCollection`](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoCollection.html#find-org.bson.conversions.Bson-), (where find() is [`FindIterable<TDocument> find(Bson filter)`](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#find-org.bson.conversions.Bson-)), not `DBCollection`.

`MongoCollection` is newer, since it's available after v3.0 release. Thus, maybe you would like to stick with it, instead of `DBCollection`.